# Using Legacy Header in C++20 Modules with Clang Compiler

Tags: c++, module, clang, c++20

I am trying to write some codes in c++20 standard. I write some simple code in  c++ module way. And I write '`#include <iostream>`' because '`import <iostream>`' can not be compiled in clang-15.0.2 compiler. Then I meet compile error.

The code is:

```cpp
// md.ixx
module;
#include <iostream>
export module md;

export int func() {
    return 114514;
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
import md;

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto val = func();
    cout<<val<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile error is:

```
error: main.cpp:10:5: error: missing '#include <iostream>'; 'cout' must be declared before it is used
    cout<<val<<endl;
    ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\iostream:40:57: note: declaration here is not visible
__PURE_APPDOMAIN_GLOBAL extern _CRTDATA2_IMPORT ostream cout;
                                                        ^
main.cpp:10:16: error: missing '#include <ostream>'; 'endl' must be declared before it is used
    cout<<val<<endl;
               ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\ostream:1000:51: note: declaration here is not visible
basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL endl(
                                                  ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\ostream:269:9: error: missing '#include <xiosbase>'; 'ios_base' must be declared before it is used
        ios_base::iostate _State = ios_base::goodbit;
        ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\xiosbase:170:28: note: declaration here is not visible
class _CRTIMP2_PURE_IMPORT ios_base : public _Iosb<int> { // base class for ios
```

And If I delete `#include<iostream>` in file `md.ixx`. It can be successfully compiled.

So is there any solution to using `<iostream>` in both `main.cpp` and `md.ixx`?

Thank you a lot.